# How to handle error: Task exception was never retrieved

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

While scanning bunch of websites using the below function I received an error (see below). Would there be any `except` step I should add to the function below to handle such error or there is something wrong with my `try` / `except` part in my function?

**function:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import io
import requests.exceptions
import time
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
import io 

df = pd.read_csv('myScan.csv') 
urls = df.T.values.tolist()[2]

results = {}
status = {}
async def scrape(url):
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=(3, 6))
        r.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        if soup.body:
            data = {
                "coming soon": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("coming soon", re.I)),
                "Opening Soon": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Opening Soon", re.I)),
                "Under Construction": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Under Construction", re.I)),
                "Currently Unavailable": soup.body.findAll(text = re.compile("Currently Unavailable", re.I)),
                "button_2": soup.findAll(text = re.compile('button_2.js'))}
            results[url] = data
    except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError, requests.exceptions.Timeout, requests.exceptions.MissingSchema):
        status[url] = "Connection Error"
    except (requests.exceptions.HTTPError):
        status[url] = "Http Error"
    except (requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects):
        status[url] = "Redirects"
    except (requests.exceptions.RequestException) as err:
        status[url] = "Fatal Error: " + err + url
    else:
        status[url] = "OK"

async def main():
    await asyncio.wait([scrape(url) for url in urls])


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()

comingList= []
openingList = []
underList = []
button_2 = []
statusList = []

for url in urls:
    if(not results.get(url)):
        statusList.append(status.get(url))
        comingList.append("-")
        openingList.append("-")
        underList.append("-")
        button_2.append("-")
    else:
        statusList.append(status.get(url))
        comingList.append("x" if len(results[url].get("coming soon")) > 0 else "-")
        openingList.append("x" if len(results[url].get("Opening Soon")) > 0 else "-")
        underList.append("x" if len(results[url].get("Under Construction")) > 0 else "-")
        button_2.append("x" if len(results[url].get("button_2")) > 0 else "-")

df["comingSoon"] = pd.DataFrame(comingList, columns=['comingSoon'])
df["openingSoon"] = pd.DataFrame(openingList, columns=['openingSoon'])
df["underConstruction"] = pd.DataFrame(underList, columns=['underConstruction'])
df["button_2"] = pd.DataFrame(button_2, columns=['button_2'])
df['status'] = pd.DataFrame(statusList, columns=['Status'])

df.to_csv('myScanCompleted.csv', index=False)
```

**Error:**

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-43943' coro=<scrape() done, defined at crawler.py:69> exception=TypeError('can only concatenate str (not "ChunkedEncodingError") to str')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 697, in _update_chunk_length
self.chunk_left = int(line, 16)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
yield
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 764, in read_chunked
self._update_chunk_length()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 701, in _update_chunk_length
raise InvalidChunkLength(self, line)
urllib3.exceptions.InvalidChunkLength: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 753, in generate
for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 572, in stream
for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 793, in read_chunked
self._original_response.close()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/response.py", line 455, in _error_catcher
raise ProtocolError("Connection broken: %r" % e, e)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 71, in scrape
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=(3, 6))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 697, in send
    r.content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 831, in content
    self._content = b''.join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or b''
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 756, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 89, in scrape
    status[url] = "Fatal Error: " + err + url
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "ChunkedEncodingError") to str
```

Comment: Hi Greg, I updated code in my question. Would you be able to tell what could fail or how to achieve the above scenario in a more robust way? thank you!

Comment: the error message that traces to your script is about requests.get(), so might it be just a timeout error?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error. Can't speak as to why, but switching from the `html.parser` parser to `lxml` fixed it for me.

Might be useful: [difference between parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#differences-between-parsers)